# Which country was leading "rules-based order" of the west before the USA?

Tags: united-states, international-relations

[What does "rules-based order" mean?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25615/17569)

Which country was leading "rules-based order" of the west before the USA?

Which country was the leader of the West before WW2 and before WW1?

Comment: The rule is whatever the strongest country say it is. It has always been so. How many double standard things have the powerful nations done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kind of cooperation that exists today between the western countries is a relatively recent phenomenon, but its underpinnings can be found in the 1814 [Congress of Vienna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congress_of_Vienna) and [Treaty of Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Paris_(1814)) in which the European powers came together after the Napoleanic Wars to discuss the prevention of future wars of that scale and proposed that a "general congress" be held between the warring powers. Prior to this time, while there was a general principle of non-interference established by the [Peace of Westphalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_of_Westphalia), this marked greater integration and consensus on international norms as far as the "rules-based order" goes.

At this time (early 1800s) the [UK was the world hegemon](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20097288), and would remain so until the US began to take this role with the world wars. As the dominant European power it was the defender of this western "rules-based order" until the US took the mantle.